# Why isn't this abstract class working with circular dependency?

Tags: c++, abstract-class, circular-dependency

When I compile my code, I get:

```
 "src/gameObject.cpp:8:13: error: expected unqualified-id before 'class' GameObject::class Component& getComponent(const std::string &name)"
```

alongside several other errors of a similar type. I'm not sure if the problem has to do with the abstract class or the forward declaration of the class. I have tried troubleshooting for the past day and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to fix this dependency. The intention is for "Components" to contain a pointer that points to the `gameObject` that they are owned by and for `gameObjects` to contain a list of different implementations of the Component abstract class. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

Component.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <string>

class GameObject;

class Component{
public:
    
    GameObject* gameObject;

    std::string name;

    virtual void update(const float &dt) = 0;

    virtual void draw() = 0;

    virtual void start() = 0;

    virtual ~Component();
    
};
```

GameObject.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

#include "Transform.h"

class GameObject{
public:
    Transform transform;

    GameObject(const std::string &name, const Transform &transform);

    class Component& getComponent(const std::string &name);

    void addComponent(const class Component &c);

    std::vector<class Component> getAllComponents();

    class Component& removeComponent(const std::string &name);

    void update(const float &dt);

private:
    std::vector<class Component> components;
    
    std::string name;
    
};
```

gameObject.cpp

```
#include "Component.h"

GameObject::GameObject(const std::string &name, const Transform &transform)
:name(name), transform(transform)
{}

GameObject::class Component& getComponent(const std::string &name)
{
    for(Component& c : components)
    {
        if(c.name == name)
            return c;
        else
            return nullptr;
    }
}

GameObject::void addComponent(const Component &c)
{
    components.push_back(c);
    c.gameObject = this;
}

GameObject::class Component& removeComponent(const std::string &name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < components.size(); i++) {
        if(components[i].name == name)
            components.erase(i);
}

GameObject::std::vector<class Component> getAllComponents()
{
    return components;
}

GameObject::void update(const float &dt)
{
    for(Component c : components)
    {
        c.update(dt);
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add `GameObject::` before `getComponent` when defining the member function outside class.

Comment: `GameObject::class`?? can this even compile? Keyword in such place!

Comment: I notice that `GameObject.h` doesn't `#include "Component.h"`?

Comment: ... or no forward declaration of `Component` in `GameObject.h`

Comment: All of the signatures in `GameObject.cpp` look really wrong. For example the correct signature would be `void GameObject::addComponent(const Component &c)` and remove all the `class` keywords that are incorrectly placed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, you don't need to added the *class key* `class` everywhere a class name is expected. Often it is optional in C++ unlike C.

##### Problem 2

Next, you're actually defining a **free function** named `getComponent` instead of a member function. For defining the member function outside the class, we first *have to be in the scope of the class* which we can do by using the **scope resolution operator** `::` as shown below.

```
class GameObject{
public:
    Transform transform;

    GameObject(const std::string &name, const Transform &transform);
//--v------------------------------------------------>removed class keyword from here
    Component& getComponent(const std::string &name);

    void addComponent(const class Component &c);
//--------------v------------------------------------>removed class keyword from here
    std::vector< Component> getAllComponents();
//-v---------------------------------------------------->removed class keyword from here
    Component& removeComponent(const std::string &name);

    void update(const float &dt);

private:
//--------------v-------------------------->removed class keyword from here
    std::vector< Component> components;
    
    std::string name;
    
};
//-------------------vv---------------------------------->uses scope resolution operator here
Component& GameObject::getComponent(const std::string &name)
{
    for(Component& c : components)
    {
        if(c.name == name)
            return c;
        else
            return NULL;
    }
}
```

##### Problem 3

The return type of the member function while implementing it outside the class should be placed before the name of the member function. This means `GameObject::void addComponent(const Component &c)` is **invalid** and should be changed to:

```
vvvv------------------------------------------------>return type void is placed before naming the member function
void GameObject::addComponent(const Component &c)
{

}
vvvvvvvvv---------------------------------------->return type Component& is placed before naming the member function
Component& GameObject::removeComponent(const std::string &name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < components.size(); i++) {
        if(components[i].name == name)
            components.erase(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to put `class` before a class name each time you are using it. Remove all the `class` keywords except the ones in a forward-declaration for a class, i.e.

```
class GameObject;
```

and those introducing a class definition, i.e.

```
class GameObject { /*...*/ };
```

Some of your uses of `class` are just redundant. Some are potentially dangerous. And others are out-right invalid syntax.

---

Also, a function returning a `Component&`, not `void`, should have a `return` statement. Otherwise calling it will have undefined behavior. `NULL` is also not something a function returning a reference can return. A reference must always be bound to an object. There is no `NULL` state like for pointers.

---

Also see the other answer for more problems.